# .click()/.trigger('click') doesn't work with Tampermonkey in Spotify

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, spotify, tampermonkey

I'm trying to write a script that will skip to the next song on Spotify after a certain event, I can't get it to work.

I'm aware there is a lot of already asked questions like this here, but I tried all the answers but they don't work for me.

When I try using Chrome console these work just fine, but not in the script:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('spoticon-skip-forward-16')[0].click(); /*or*/
document.getElementsByClassName('spoticon-skip-forward-16')[0].trigger('click');
```

---

```
jQuery('spoticon-skip-forward-16:first').click(); /*or*/
jQuery('spoticon-skip-forward-16:first').trigger('click');
```

---

```
   jQuery('spoticon-skip-forward-16:first').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).css("color", "yellow");
        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);
        this.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    });
```

**jQuery('spoticon-skip-forward-16:first')** can be substituted for **jQuery('spoticon-skip-forward-16').get(0)** or **jQuery('spoticon-skip-forward-16')[0]**, they all work in console but not in Tampermonkey.

I know the event happens because I've set to change the button color before click and it happens every time.

I get no errors and I tried try and catch but nothing happens.

Comment: are you sure `document.getElementsByClassName('spoticon-skip-forward-16')[0].trigger('click');` works? I'm surprised that a DOM element has a `trigger` method

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add **.** Whenever you are referring an element by class in jQuery you need to add **.** in front of the class name.

**Mistake**

```
jQuery('spoticon-skip-forward-16:first').click(); /*or*/
jQuery('spoticon-skip-forward-16:first').trigger('click');
```

**Change to**

```
jQuery('.spoticon-skip-forward-16:first').click(); /*or*/
jQuery('.spoticon-skip-forward-16:first').trigger('click');
```

[Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLuo1ag5/)

```js
$('.spoticon-skip-forward-16').click(function(){
 console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});

$('.spoticon-skip-forward-16:first').click(); 
$('.spoticon-skip-forward-16:last').click(); 

$('.spoticon-skip-forward-16').each(function () {
  $(this).css({
    color: 'yellow',
    background: '#000'
  });
  var clickEvent  = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);
  this.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="spoticon-skip-forward-16" id="btn1">
Submit
</button>

<button type="submit" class="spoticon-skip-forward-16" id="btn2">
Submit
</button>

<button type="submit" class="spoticon-skip-forward-16" id="btn3">
Submit
</button>
```